# Erro com o jQuery.load() só no Safari (OSX)

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou com um problema usando o jquery.load() p carregar parte de um outro documento que só ocorre no Safari no Mac(nas versoes mais recentes: Safari 7.1 e OSx 10.9.5). Em todos os outros navegadores (inclusive IE) funcionam perfeitamente.

O erro no console do Safari q recebo é o seguinte:

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.dominio.com.br/arquivo_a_ser_carregado.php. Origin http://dominio.com.br is not allowed by Acess-Control-Allow-Origin**

Pelo que pesquisei esse erro acontece qdo há um requisição em ajax entre dois dominios diferentes.
Apesar de todos os arquivos estarem no mesmo domínio e na mesma pasta, pelo erro que é mostrado, o domínio de origem e o que está tentando carregar o arquivo está com um pequena diferenção: um deles está sem o **WWW** e provavelmente isso que está causando o erro.

O código que estou usando para carregar é o seguinte:

```
$('.holder').load("arquivo_a_ser_carregado.php #conteudoPort",function(){ 
    console.log('ok'); 
});
```

Como disse anteriormente, esse erro só esta ocorrendo no Safari no Mac. Mesmo colocando a url absoluta continuo recebendo o mesmo erro.

Se alguem já passou por isso e tiver alguma luz para me ajudar, agradeço muito.
Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Caso tenha controle do servidor que responde à requisição ajax, tente configurar o response header com:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Mesmo variações pequenas, como o `www` pode influenciar em como o navegador identifica o domínio.

Como está usando php, também pode tentar usar:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

**Atenção para o `*`. Substitua-o conforme o necessário, caso contrário seu domínio aceitará requisições de qualquer outro domínio.**